# how does this angularjs directive get called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand caitp's [angular comment system](https://github.com/caitp/ui-comments) without much luck and was wondering if someone could help me out.

There is a [directive](https://github.com/caitp/ui-comments/blob/master/src/comments.js) called comments which looks like this:

```
.directive('comments', function($compile, $interpolate, commentsConfig) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '?^comment',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: function() { return commentsConfig.containerTemplate; },
    scope: {
      'comments': '=commentData'
    }, 
    controller: function() {},
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, elem, attr, comment) {
        var self = elem.controller('comments'),
             parentCollection = comment ? comment.comments : null;

    // Setup $commentsController
    if (parentCollection) {
      self.commentsDepth = parentCollection.commentsDepth + 1;
      self.commentsRoot = parentCollection.commentsRoot;
      self.commentsParent = parentCollection;
    } else {
      self.commentsDepth = 1;
      self.commentsRoot = null;
      var depthLimit = angular.isDefined(attr.commentDepthLimit) ?
                       attr.commentDepthLimit :
                       commentsConfig.depthLimit;
      if (typeof depthLimit === 'string') {
        depthLimit = $interpolate(depthLimit, false)(scope.$parent);
        if (typeof depthLimit === 'string') {
          depthLimit = parseInt(depthLimit, 10);
        }
      }

      if (typeof depthLimit !== 'number' || depthLimit !== depthLimit) {
        // Avoid NaN and non-numbers
        depthLimit = 0;
      }

      self.commentsDepthLimit = depthLimit;
    }

        scope.commentsDepth = self.commentsDepth;
        attr.$observe('orderBy', function(newval, oldval) {
          scope.commentOrder = newval || commentsConfig.orderBy;
        });
      }
    }
  };
})
```

and I believe the code which calls the directive is this:

```
<div class="comments">
  <comment ng-repeat="comment in comments" comment-data="comment"></comment>
</div>
```

My question is this: for the link pre function in the directive, where are the input parameters being sent? Where is the value of comment being set?

Comment: comment-data="comment" sets that parameter. and in the directive definition scope: {
      'comments': '=commentData'
    },  completes the binding.

Comment: It must be `<comments></comments>` or `<div comments></div>`

Comment: Thanks @katmanco . I see now. and "comments" is a scope variable from the controller.

Comment: Wait, actually I don't see it anymore. I see comments is set with commentsData, but for the function `function(scope, elem, attr, comment)` what is calling this and what is comment set to?